# RawArray crashes the kernel

Tags: bugs, undocumented, crash

**fixed in 10.0.2**

---

RawArray seems to crash the kernel on my machine

```
RawArray["Byte", {}]
```

Is this a bug? Any insights why this happens?

My system:

version 10.01 on Mac OS X 10.0

[image]

**Update**

I heard back from the technical support that "a correction is already being
worked on for a future version".

Comment: Well, it *is* an undocumented thing, not meant for public consumption ... do you have any reason to believe that it should work?

Comment: @Szabolcs It has been used in the documentation example of Raster3D (under Neat Examples). I was playing with the parameters in the example and it crashed the kernel.

Comment: I can reproduce the crash on Win7 64 Pro SP1, Mma 10.0.1.0 . I think that crashing the kernel is not an acceptable behaviour, irrespective if its an undocumented function or not. Anybody available to test on Linux?

Comment: @rhermans If you were implementing hybrid Mathematica/C libraries, I think you woulnd't say that.  Mathematica happens to be a language where it's not easy to hide the internal wiring.  "Undocumented" often really means that it's a helper function for the developer, not meant for the end user.  Implementing checks to make sure all arguments passed to a function are correct and reporting errors if they aren't is *a lot* of work, not to mention it also hurts performance.  It just makes no sense to include these checks for a function not meant for public consumption.

Comment: Of course if `RawArray` is used somewhere in the documentation that makes things a bit different, but we knew Mathematica was messing ... BTW it also crashes in v9 but not in v8.

Comment: @Szabolcs sure, I'm not a professional programmer and the industry may have their own standards, I should have emphasized that is only my humble opinion. Still, we are talking about a high end commercial product, and *IMHO* an internal module could crash, but never the whole kernel nor the front end. Shroud we add the [tag:bugs] tag?

Comment: @rhermans I'm not a professional programmer either, but I use LibraryLink a lot, so I implement stuff like this.  What I am trying to say is that when you extend Mathematica using C, it is simply *unavoidable* that some functions will crash the whole kernel when used incorrectly.  Then we can put a layer on top of these "raw" functions which check for wrong arguments to avoid such crashes.  But there's always that underlying, non-public function that *will* crash if used wrong.  It's simply a matter of how low level languages and the OS works.

Comment: @rhermans  It is technically impossible not to have any such functions that crash. What is possible is to hide them, but Mathematica is not very good at hiding stuff.  It's a different matter that RawArray is not really hidden, and it even appears in a documentation example ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can reproduce the crash on Win7 64 Pro SP1, Mma 10.0.1.0

This has been fixed in version 10.0.2. On windows 7:

```
$Version
(*10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)*)

RawArray["Byte", {}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No crash. Just the above error message.